# Atom files different color after using git-plus

Tags: git, atom-editor

After I initialised git-plus on atom, all my files have become this colour until I commit it. I've uninstalled git-plus and all of this still persists. Even repositories without a .git folder in them still have this tint in the treeview. Is there any way to make it so that I have to at least make it a .git repository before it tracks the commits?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to only make the tint happen if you're in a `.git` repository, maybe someone else can help with that.

I personally didn't like the tree-view git colors either, so I just removed them completely. You can do so by adding the following to your stylesheet:

```
// Remove Git highlighting from tree view
.status-modified,
.status-added,
.status-renamed,
.status-removed {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;

  &.directory > .list-item {
    color: inherit !important;
    background-color: inherit !important;
  }

  &.directory.selected > .list-item {
    color: inherit !important;
    background-color: inherit !important;
  }
}
```